# Github Page suddenly not rendering CSS despite nothing changing

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've been hosting a personal page through Github Pages using Jekyll for a couple years now. It's worked perfectly until this evening. I pushed a new blog post out and suddenly the blog portion of the site is unable to render any of my CSS (it still works in portions of the site not generated by Jekyll). I've checked everything in my commits – nothing seems to have changed – and even rolled back everything to an older commit (from a few months ago) without any improvement. Have there been any changes to GH Pages that could have caused this? Any clues?

Repo: https://github.com/gweintraub/gweintraub.github.io

Page: http://gabeweintraub.com/

Comment: What is the exact problem of the CSS file? Main stylesheet is loading fine.

Comment: I can't identify any sort of problem with the file itself.

Comment: There are 404 errors in the console for the missing assets and CSS, so it seems like a broken reference, I just can't figure out where that broken reference would be or how it could have broken without changing anything.

Comment: I just see wrong urls for background images in lightbox.css, rest of the site seems to be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `includes/head.html` you are including the CSS file with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

but it isn't taking into account the `site.url` variable, to generate a complete url with `site.url` and `site.baseurl` use the `absolute_url` filter:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'css/main.css' | absolute_url }}">
```

Now your links would be generated fine when you visit deeper levels of the website.

Comment: This, along with a few other similar changes, did the trick. I'm very confused how this managed to happen since in theory nothing was changed and it ran smoothly for a couple years until today, but I'm grateful it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @gweintraub I think I'm having the same problem - can you say what the "few other similar changes" are?

Comment: Important if you test this: for me `absolute_url` had no effect on the local jekyll build (which makes sense), so do push to GitHub to see the result.